# How to change Interface Metric permanently in CentOS

Tags: linux-networking, metrics

My Config:

1. Guest OS - CentOS7
2. Host OS - Windows 7
3. Interface - 3 (`enp0s3`, `enp0s8`, `enp0s9`)
4. Installed in Virtual Box
5. `enp0s8` is Bridge to `wlan0`(For Internet)
6. `enp0s3` and `enp0s9` are host-only

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
0.0.0.0         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 enp0s9
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 enp0s8
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s8
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s9`

I added `METRIC=10` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8` and then restarted. But in `route -n` still it is showing `Metric` as `101` (As you see in above output). I tried `sudo ifconfig enp0s8 metric 10`, but no use. The `ping 8.8.8.8` is failing. If I `down` the `enp0s3`, `enp0s9`, the ping is successful. Is there is way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't set default gateways for interfaces which don't connect to the Internet.

Remove the default gateways that are defined for those interfaces. That is, delete the `GATEWAY=` line from the `ifcfg-enp0s3` and `ifcfg-enp0s9` files.

You do not need to worry about the route metric at all.

Comment: Ok, I did just you said, but still I'm not able to `ping 8.8.8.8`. Now I cant even ping gateway of `enp0s8`'s

Answer (score 2):

NetworkManager ifcfg-rh plugin is used on the Fedora and Red Hat Enterprise Linux distributions (and CentOS) to read/write configuration from/to the traditional /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-* files.

ifcfg-rh plugin variable IPV4_ROUTE_METRIC is NetworkManager specific extension not understood by traditional initscripts. For this purpose NetworkManager have to be active which is the default behaviour in CentOS7.

Add IPV4_ROUTE_METRIC=10 to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8. The lower number the higher priority. If you add this parameter for one interface you should add IPV4_ROUTE_METRIC with different priority numbers also to all remaining interfaces to keep control over routing priority.

Restart all interfaces:
ifdown ifcfg-enp0s3;ifdown ifcfg-enp0s8;ifdown ifcfg-enp0s9;ifup ifcfg-enp0s3;ifup ifcfg-enp0s8;ifup ifcfg-enp0s9

Other way to inform NetworkManager about config changes:
nmcli con reload

Check routing priority with command:
ip route show

Comment: I've just used this in RHEL8 and it worked here as well.
METRIC by itself didn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

add METRIC=10 in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8

For centos 7, this setting is permanently

Comment: OP says they tried this and it didn't work?

Comment: Simple and straightforward. Thank you.